# How do I use regular expression to recognize this sql create table pattern

Tags: python, regex

The pattern I want to recognize is for those tables whose name don't end with _code suffix( the table name shouldn't be like test_code) :

```
CREATE TABLE test1
(
    aa INT, -- comment1
    bb CHAR(10), -- comment2
    cc INT, -- comment3
    PRIMARY KEY (aa)
);
```

and this also could be one-line style like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test2( aa INT, bb CHAR(10), cc INT, PRIMARY KEY (aa));
```

I used the following regular expression but didn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE .*\n?\([.\n\;]*
```

I want to recognize them and **insert a sentence between the ")" and ";"** to be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test1
(
    aa INT, -- comment1
    bb CHAR(10), -- comment2
    cc INT, -- comment3
    PRIMARY KEY (aa)
)[sentence goes to here];
```

Please tell me how should I solve this problem.

Comment: So are you wanting to match or replace?

Comment: match the create table sentence and insert a sentence between ")" and ";"

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
import re
rgx = re.compile(r"^\s*CREATE\s+TABLE\s+([\w\d]+)\s*(\(.*\))\s*;\s*",re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

def sqlsub(sql, statement):
  m = rgx.match(sql)
  if m and not m.group(1).endswith("_code"):
    return "CREATE TABLE %s %s %s;"%(m.group(1),m.group(2),statement)
```

Comment: Actually there is one more problem on this code.  Because I read line by line the SQL code, which includes many sentences like create table, drop table, alter table... So It's not easy to separate the create table sentence to use on your sqlsub function.